# Using "while True" for http requests in Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, python-requests

I am trying to populate a MongoDB collection with all articles (JSON object of the requests result) from and API called "Spaceflight News".

I know this is pretty basic, but is there an elegant/correct alternative to the following Python snippet code, I mean without using the classic "while True" looping?

```py
start = 0
articles_collec = []

while True:
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://api.spaceflightnewsapi.net/v3/articles?_limit=100&_sort=id&_start={start}"
    )    

    documents = json.loads(r.text)

    for item in list(documents):
        articles_collec.append(item)

    if documents == []:
        try:
            articles.insert_many(articles_collec)
        except:            
            break

    start += 100
```

**Edit:**
Changed to this, but still don't know what to test to break the loop and manage to complete the insertions.
Without the loop break, after all the insertions I get a "BulkWriteError" from pymongo.

```
start = 0

articles_collec = []

request = requests.get("https://api.spaceflightnewsapi.net/v3/articles/count")

total_articles = int(request.content.decode('utf-8'))

while True:
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://api.spaceflightnewsapi.net/v3/articles?_sort=id&_start={start}&_limit={total_articles // 10}"
    )

    documents = json.loads(r.text)

    for item in list(documents):
        articles_collec.append(item)

    if documents == []:        
            articles.insert_many(articles_collec)

    start += total_articles // 10
```

**Edit 2:**
Added this at the end of the while. It worked, but I am still confused how the whole thing works since I checked this before in order to make the insertions (insert_many). I think I need an explanation for how the request.get works alongside the rest of the code inside the while.

```
if documents == []:
        break
```

Comment: The `try` looks odd. You only want to break out of the loop if the insertion fails? Seems like that's something you want to try *after* you break out of the loop once the request stops returning items.

Comment: This may be better fitted for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @rob when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).

Comment: I am trying to populate a MongoDB collection with all articles (JSON object of the requests result) from this Spaceflight News API. If the parameter "limit" is not provided the API returns only 10 articles. I did notice the "try catch" looks odd but it was the only way I found to stop the looping without getting a "BulkWriteError" from pymongo after it inserts all documents. I tried other things like using the "articles/count" route from the API and iterating until it reaches the last article but it simply does not insert data. I am not sure how this HTTP request work inside the loop...

Answer (score 0):

For this particular website, the start parameter is valid for values in excess of 11,000. Once you go beyond a start value that returns nothing of significance, the HTTP response will still be 200. Therefore, a *while True* construct makes sense. You would just test the JSON response and, if it's an empty list, you would break.

I'm not sure why you're incrementing start by 100. Maybe you're only looking for sample data rather than getting everything.

Having said that, for such a vast amount of data you should consider multithreading for the database insert part.